# Add login Activity afterwards

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I started my android app by making a `ListViewActivity`.

Now I decided to make a `LogInScreenActivity`. Do i have to declare the `LogInScreenActivity` as `MainActivity`?

Or can i change the `MainActivity` manually? I'm using Android Studio and new ad Androidl

Comment: You can change it from manifest.xml file.
Just replace activity name where you have intent filter with Main action.

Comment: Thank you! It's the same answer as below right? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. How you name your activities doesn't matter for that case.
Use

```html
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

for the activity you want to be the "main" activity